# GIS base map solutions

Tags: maps

I'm new to GIS development, and am looking for a mapping solution for a web app. The map will be fairly complex with 4-5 different layers. I'm looking to convert shapefiles into a usable geo-coded format, to be served from a few different layer specific API's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nextgis.com](https://my.nextgis.com/signup/?next=/webgis/). Vector layer upload support (ShapeFile, GeoJSON). Complex styles (QGIS, MapServer) support. CORS for using in your own Leaflet or OL widget - support. Prebuild web maps support.

[image]

Some [other features](http://nextgis.com/blog/news-nextgis-com-4/).